# Including the same module file within itself in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning ruby and about modules and mixins..

I tried the following code. The name of the ruby file test.rb.

```
module Mod1
  def Mod1.sayHello()
    puts "Hello Mod1"
  end

end

module Mod2
  def Mod2.sayHello()
    puts "Hello Mod2"
  end
end


class TestMod
  require 'file'
  Mod1.sayHello
end

t = TestMod.new
```

I am suprised to the output:
Hello Mod1
Hello Mod1 (twice)

I am don't have an explanation for this, can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

You did not define your `initialize` method for your class (the constructor). You are simply executing `Mod1.sayHello` inside the class definition (it is even executed before creating the instance). Try to comment out your `t = TestMod.new` statement. The output will still stay visible.
Since you include the exact same file, this ends up being executed twice (the file does not get included another time afterwards; ruby prevents this). The class should look like this:

```
class TestMod
  def initialize
    Mod1.sayHello
  end
end
```

Why did you include the file anyway? This does not make sense to me.

**EDIT:** Removed a mistake.

I would recommend to replace the `Mod1` and `Mod2` inside your module definitions with `self`. This way you wont have to change the name everywhere if it changes some time.

Comment: That won't work...  `def Mod1.sayHello` is the same as saying `def self.sayHello`.  In order for the call to Mod1.sayHello to work, the sayHello method must be a class method and not an instance method.

Comment: Also, I believe if no initialize method is defined, ruby acts on the first method it encounters as a constructor when instantiating an object.

Comment: @Brian: Your first statement is true. I made a mistake here and updated my post accordingly. But i do not believe that ruby uses the first method it encounters. `Mod1.sayHello` is a call to the method. This works exactly like the `attr_accessor`-method for example. It is executed at class definition, not instantiation.

Comment: You are right - my second comment is completely wrong & actually has nothing to do w/ the issue.  :-)

Comment: @all: Thanks for the reply! I am just trying to play around with it, I know this is a crazy thing to do, but i am learning anyways! Thanks!